# Why i get this error when try to create android alarm?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,i want to create simple alarm manager in my application,write this code:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Intent i = new Intent(testSendWithFood.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(testSendWithFood.this, 5, i, 0);
                        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pi);
```

but in this line:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

in this part:

```
this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

i get this error:
[image]

Why?

Comment: Where calling `getSystemService` method?? In Normal class or in Fragment,..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code appears to be inside an inner class of your Activity/Service. In that scope, an unqualified `this` refers to the current instance of that inner class, not the current Activity/Service instance, which is what you want to call `getSystemService()` on. To specify the current Activity/Service instance, prepend the class name to `this`.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) testSendWithFood.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```